# XDSoft jQuery DateTimePicker -- how to get Selected datetime?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the plugin demo page with examples:

http://xdsoft.net/jquery-plugins/demo/datetimepicker/

I am stuck with getting selected datetime out of it. Can you please help me out here?

Comment: do you read something on page from your link? event `onChangeDateTime` or what your problem?

Comment: @Waki yes I know about this. Callback seemed to me as an overkill, I thought there must be a method like getDate() or something. I spent quite a time googling for it, no success, so I've posted the question.

Comment: yes. I have default selection set to some date. If user is ok with this, he will not reselect it and therefore the callback will not happen. I made a dirty workaround for this for now.

Comment: and what about $('#datetimepicker').val();? Have a look here: https://coding.kz/dev/datetimepicker.html

Comment: @IlyaSmagin is right, there is no simple way to get the `Date` from the control.  There was something mentioned in docs : `getCurrentValue` but I think it's been removed.  NOTE: the .val() I think may only give you a string, not a Date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://coding.kz/dev/datetimepicker.html

I think at create page need set value *(current datetime)* to your field, then you can get it.

Comment: Not working. I am using inline version of the control: "jQuery('#datetimepicker3').val()" at the example page.

Comment: @Ilya Smagin added inline version